# Calculation of class members

Tags: java, oop

While coding, I encountered following situation:

I have a class, let's call it `C`. It has an attribute `A` of arbitrary type which must be calculated first:

```java
public class C {
    private int A;

    public C(...) {
        ...
    }

    public void calculateA() {
        A = 42;
    }

    public int getA() {
    }
}
```

My question now is, how to implement the getter `getA` properly. Should I check whether A is defined and throw an exception otherwise?

Or should I just call `calculateA` in `getA` if it is not set?

What is the best choice for that kind of problem?

---

**Edit:** OK, I gave a bad Example. `A` cannot be calculated in the constructor, because the calculation method will return a new instance of the same class, which will lead to an infinite recursion.

Comment: Why not set a default value for A in your constructor?

Comment: Depends. But if it's an integer, how will you differentiate it from an unset value? Is `0` an invalid value? Is it a long-running calculation (e.g., does it really matter)?

Comment: That would make sense for this example. But in my case, there is no default value which makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a design question, somewhat inappropriate for this forum.

If it is responsibility of the client to call `calculateA()` before `getA()` then `getA()` can throw exception if it has not been calculated. The fact that `a` is primitive is irrelevant, you could either initialize to an invalid value -- e.g. if it is a length type of entity then initialize it to -1 -- or use another `boolean` variable or use an `Integer` that would be null, whatever.

Understand that this creates a *temporal dependency* -- clients are required to call methods in a fixed order. This is usually frowned upon, but there might be circumstances to justify it, you have to call `Car.start()` before calling `Car.stop()`.

On the other hand if `C` "owns" `A` then it is its responsibility to calculate it. It can do this in several ways:

- Eagerly, in its `<init>`, if all necessary information is avaialable
- Lazily/On-demand but cached, call `calculateA()` first time `A` is needed.
- Calculate every time it is called, though `getA()` may be a misleading name in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I think -

```
public class C {
    private int A = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    ...
    public int getA() {
         if(A==Integer.MIN_VALUE )// Assume Integer.MIN_VALUE when it is not calculated
            throw new RuntimeException();
         return A;
    }
}
```

It could not be 100% proof as it is assumed `Integer.MIN_VALUE` could not be calculated value.

Make you instance variable `A` as Integer Object instead of primitive `int`, so you can set as null which could be easier to determine the state.

Comment: Precludes the possibility of zero being a valid value for `A`.

Comment: Er... but it'll be 0 unless explicitly set to something else (and assumes 0 isn't a reasonable value, which isn't stated).

Comment: yap its really a assumption, 0 or MIN_VALUE or MAX_VALUE

Comment: I would rather throw an [`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html): *Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.*

Comment: that would more accurate runtime exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad example, because int is a primitive type.  It's never null.  It's initialized to zero.

But your point is valid for reference types.

I would consider it a poor a design to allow a null reference to a private member.  The constructor should initialize the object to be 100% ready to go.

Comment: I do not totally agree with this. The object must just be consistent at the end of the constructor. In some use cases, a null pointer might be consistent e.g. An object which represents a Node can have a parent Node which might be null (case of root Node).

Comment: Agreed.  I'm thinking about cases like a List child.  It's entirely reasonable to initialize it to point to an empty List implementation.  I should not have to pay the price of checking to see if it's null every time I try to access it.

Comment: In your particular case, knowing that a null Node means root is information that's appropriate to pass back to the user.  OR I might have a special Root instance of Node, and a method isRoot() that returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If the calculation is static you might as well call the calculateA() function from the constructor.

```
public C(...) {
        ...
        calculateA()
    }

public void calculateA() {
    A = 42;
}
```

If the contract of the getter() dictates that only valid and calculated values of `A` will be returned, calculate `A` before returning it.

If `A` cannot be calculated for some reason and if it makes sense in your program to stop execution before calculating anything further with an invalid `A`, throw an exception.